# Freeing a multidimensional array when allocation fails

Tags: c, malloc, free, calloc

Say I allocate a two-dimensional array:

```
int main(void)
{
        long int **arr;
        int i;
        int j;

        arr = calloc(2, sizeof(long int *));
        if (!arr) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                arr[i] = calloc(10, sizeof(long int));
                if (!arr[i]) {
                        for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                                free(arr[j]);
                        }
                        free(arr);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
}
```

Should I include the `free()`-loop in the test condition if memory allocation fails

```
if (!arr[i]) {
        for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                free(arr[j]);
        }
        free(arr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

or is it usually enough to just `exit()` with failure when I don't want the program to move on?

```
if (!arr[i]) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: If you're terminating your process regardless, freeing *anything* seems akin to contract-paving the road you're taking to drive off a cliff.

Comment: Thanks for the analogy. If the program were to move on this kind of error handling would be advised? I find it hard to get really good resources about error handling in `C`.

Comment: If you were to *continue* execution you would clearly want to clean-house (and fix your `j`-loop in doing so, as it is not correct). But if you're going to throw up your hands and surrender, there is little reason for it.

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed now. Btw the analogy part wasn't meant to be sassy. I just found your analogy quite nice!

Comment: Didn't take it as such, so no worries. Best of luck.

Comment: best method that I know of...   after allocation of the array of pointer, set all the pointers to NULL.  (it is ok to pass NULL to free())  then when it is time to recover / free all allocated memory, just loop through the array of pointer, passing each entry to free().  I usually use memset() to initialize the array of pointer to all NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are exiting the program in case of allocation failure, therefore no harm in doing this. You can use second snippet.

---

C does not provide direct support for error handling, aka exception handling. On MSVC you can try this (***Note that this is not the part of C standard***):

```
void exceptionExample() {
    int *p = NULL;
    __try {
        p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p = 5;
        printf("%d\n",*p);
    }
    __finally {
        free(p);
    }
}
```

Suggested readings: [C Programming/Error handling](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Error_handling), [Error handling in C](http://mylinuxbook.com/error-handling-in-c-programming-on-linux/).

Comment: Thanks, @haccks. As this would be an invalid question: Do you have a reading recommendation where `C` error handling is discussed?

Comment: Well you can go through [this](http://csserver.evansville.edu/~amr63/linux/unix_programming/unix-memory/unix-memory.html#c_alloc_malloc)

Comment: I meant error handling in general. There doesn't seem to be a good book out there that outlines good practices in dealing with errors. In fact most books on `C` skip error handling in most programs for reasons of clarity. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You can learn to use `goto` probably you've been warned not to do so, but it really helps writing good error handling without repeating yourself. Also, sometimes you don't want to finish the program on allocation failure, say for example that you need to do some cleanup before exit, so you might handle that instead of just ending the program. And you could even write an allocator function to take care of failure outside of it in a more compact way.

Comment: C doesn't have exceptions, so anything you might have will be DIY.  On the other hand, people now want to handle errors with fields or bits, so that should be amenable to C.  There might even be a package out there.